# Can a selection object be created without any user interaction?

Tags: javascript, selection

Can a [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Selection) object be created without any user interaction? `window.getSelection()` does return a `Selection` object, but you can't  [modify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Selection/modify) it unless the user has some sort of selection made.

Is it possible to create a selection which starts at the very first element on the page and then be able to `modify()` it, without the need for the user to do anything?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/L5M3U/

It doesn't select anything on page load, but if you click on anything it does make a selection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, then yes, you can programmatically set the selection using its `addRange()` method. For example, to select the whole of the document's `<body>` element when the page loads, you could do:

```
function selectBody() {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(document.body);
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
}

window.onload = selectBody;
```

This doesn't work on IE < 9, which has a whole different approach to ranges and selections.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was looking for. I know about the IE incompatibly and their TextRange etc., this will do just fine.

Comment: note, the `element` in `range.selectNode( element )` needs to have `innerHTML` content. Or else this won't work