# Javascript trigger selection start

Tags: javascript, browser, triggers, selection

It's possible to trigger selection **start** via javascript/jQuery?

In my opinion, *mouse text selection* can be divided into these steps:

> 1) trigger **mousedown** event and start selection
>
> 2) trigger **mousemove** and move "end point" of selection
>
> 3) trigger **mouseup** and stop selection

It's possible to trigger just **step 1)** i.e. on text in span element...
...so after that, moving mouse cursor will behave like selection waiting for mouseup?

Or **how is implemented** and **how browser knows** that selection starts?

**Rangy library:** I know this javascript library for creating custom range selection. But it's seems to me too much complicated, to simulate own selection via mouse events. I just want to tell to browser, that I started selection at *(span,offset 2)* and it should continue at **step 2)**.

Comment: Good question. Would like to know the answer to this as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mouse events on the selectable element and the document to control when you want to begin and end selection and when you want to test selection etc.

Then during selection you can use `window.getSelection()` to get information on the current selection.

Try something like this:

```
var m_MouseDown = false;

document.getElementById('selectMyContent').onmousedown = function (e) {
    m_MouseDown = true;
};

document.onmouseup = function (e) {
    m_MouseDown = false;
};

document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    if (m_MouseDown) {
        document.getElementById('showTextHere').innerHTML = getSelectionInfo();
    }        
}

function getSelectionInfo() {
    var selected = "";
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                var range = sel.getRangeAt(i);

                var txt = document.createElement('div');
                txt.appendChild(range.cloneContents());
                selected = range.startContainer.parentNode.id + ':' + range.startOffset + '-' + range.endOffset + ' "' + txt.innerHTML + '"';
            }
        }
    }
    return selected;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/nY328/10/ for an example.

Comment: Thank you for detailed example, but it's not exactly what I am trying to achieve. 
I will try to explain on your jsfiddle example:
1) when I open jsfiddle, mousedown will be automatically(onload) triggered on span#selectMyContent @ position 4.
2) so I will just move mouse and see status in span#showTextHere.

...Problem is that trigger mousedown event is not enough for browser to simulate that this mousedown event starts selection process.

...how browser knows when mousedown starts selection and when doesn't ?

Comment: Unfortunately - or rather very fortunately - you can not control the mouse and its events from a web page. You can hide the cursor and capture/take ownership of mouse, but only while your page has focus. To be able to take control of the mouse would severely compromise the security of a browser, effectively allowing a malicious party to do whatever can be achieved via mouse (on screen keyboard?) from a script.

Comment: For similar to the stated reasons above, you also can not simulate mouse events within the context of the browser as this would allow a malicious script to fire a click event on a download link, bypassing automatic download security.

Comment: You can, however, create ranges - as shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239857/can-a-selection-object-be-created-without-any-user-interaction - and using mouse events you can work out and change the selection range based on the mouse position.

Comment: Hm, I just thought, that when I am able to create custom range and also trigger mousedown event, I should be able also create "real event" of selection start. But obviously it's forbidden.

Comment: Just to be clear. Simulating start of selection process isn't possible from javascript, because it needs higher level of mouse control, which isn't allowed for security reasons? For example it's the same as if I want to simulate key combination CTRL+C for cliboard copy. It's also forbidden because of security.